# show data rating in table only when it's already rated

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter and I wanted to make table that show my rating data on specific users.

This is how i wanted it to be:

[image]

but it turned out like this:

[image]

this is my controller

```
public function datarating()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Data Rating';

        $data['rating'] = $this->some_model->get_rating_data();
        $this->load->view('template/navbar', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/item/rating_page', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/script/script', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

this is my model

```
public function get_rating_data() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('itemsrating');
        $this->db->join('users', 'itemsrating.id_user = users.id_user');
        $this->db->join('items', 'itemsrating.id_item = items.id_item');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }
```

and this is my view

```html
<div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="box-title">Data Rating</h4>
        </div><!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive" style="height: 400px ;overflow-y: scroll; ">
                        <table id="" class="table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <th>Username</th>
                                <?php foreach ($rating as $row) { ?>
                                    <th style="max-width: 120px"><?php echo "$row->item_name";?></th>
                                <?php } ?>
                        </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?php foreach ($rating as $row) {?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo "$row->username";?>
                                            <?php foreach ($rating as $row) { ?>
                                                    
                                                        <td><?php echo "$row->rating";?></td>
                                                   
                                            <?php } ?>
                                    </td>
                                    
                                </tr>

                            <?php } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
               
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my table in database

```
id_user     id_item     rating  date        komentar
U0000000001 V0000000001 3       2016-11-09  
U0000000002 V0000000002 4       2016-11-09  
U0000000003 V0000000003 5       2016-11-09
```

Comment: Your scenario is pivot table. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649419/pivot-tables-php-mysql